# Dynkin's theorem of extension of generators

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

The theorem statement is as follows.

> > $(A,\mathcal{D}(A))$ is the generator of a Feller semigroup and $(B,\mathcal{D}(B))$ extends $(A,\mathcal{D}(A))$ in the sense that $\mathcal{D}(A) \subset\mathcal{D}(B)$ and $A$ and $B$ agree on $\mathcal{D}(A)$. Suppose that $Bu = u \implies u = 0$ whenever $u \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. Then the two generators and their domains are equal.

The proof of this theorem starts as follows. Pick some arbitrary $u \in \mathcal{D}(B)$ and set

$$g:= u - Bu$$

$$h:= (\text{id}-A)^{-1}g$$

Then, $h \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. I don't know why this last statement is true. I know that $(\text{id}-A)^{-1} = U_1$ with $U$ being the resolvent of the semigroup $A$ belongs to. I don't know what class $g$ belongs to and I don't see any property of resolvents saying that they map certain classes of functions to the domains of their underlying generators. Hopefully, this is not too straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T \mathpunct{:} \mathcal{D}(T) \to V$ is an unbounded linear operator on a Banach space $V$ then we say that $T$ is invertible if it has a bounded inverse operator $T^{-1} \mathpunct{:} V \to \mathcal{D}(T)$. Let $\rho(T)$ be the set of $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda - T$ is invertible. $\rho(T)$ is called the resolvent set of $T$.

Let $X$ be the state space of the Markov processes under consideration (where $X$ is usually assumed to be a locally compact Hausdorff space with countable base) and let $C_0(X)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ which vanish at infinity, equipped with the sup norm so that $C_0(X)$ is a Banach space.

If $A$ is the generator of a Feller semigroup on $C_0(X)$ then $(0, \infty) \subset \rho(A)$ and hence, in particular, $(\text{Id} - A)$ is invertible. Since $B \mathpunct{:} \mathcal{D}(B) \to C_0(X)$ we have that $g \in C_0(X)$. Therefore $h \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ since $(\text{Id}-A)^{-1} \mathpunct{:} C_0(X) \to \mathcal{D}( \text{Id} - A) = \mathcal{D}(A)$.

Comment: Could you please explain your notation? I don't know what $C_0,X,\rho(A)$ mean. I can guess but I would like to be sure.

Comment: @Calculon I've updated my answer to include definitions of the notation you asked about. If anything else is unclear let me know!

Comment: Thank you. $u$ is in the domain of $B$ and $Bu$ is in $C_0$. Why is $g$ in $C_0$?

Comment: @Calculon Because $u$ is in $C_0(X)$? Note that generators of Feller semigroups act on the space $C_0(X)$ so $\mathcal{D}(B) \subset C_0(X)$.

Comment: @RhysSteele My definition of $1\in\rho(A)$ is that $A_1:=\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal D(A)}-A:\mathcal D(A)\to E$ ($E$ being the Banach space on which $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is defined) is injective, $R_1(A):=A_1^{-1}:A\mathcal D(A)\to\mathcal D(A)$ is bounded (and hence has an extension to $E$) and $A_1\mathcal D(A)$ is dense (and hence the aforementioned extension of $R_1(A)$ is unique). But why does the extension of $R_1(A)$ have the same range (i.e. $\mathcal D(A)$) as $R_1(A)$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d (1 of 2) That's not a definition of the resolvent set I'm used to but I think the following works. My idea is to check that $R_1(A)$ is also continuous as an operator into $\mathcal{D}(A)$ with its graph norm (which is then a complete space since $A$ is closed) and then by a standard result about extensions of bounded linear operators with values in a Banach space, $R_1(A)$ has a bounded extension to a $\mathcal{D}(A)$-valued operator, which is the same extension as you give by uniqueness.

Comment: @0xbadf00d (2/2) Let $y = A_1x \in A\mathcal{D}(A)$. Then, since $R_1(A)$ is bounded on $A\mathcal{D}(A)$, there is a $C$ such that $\|R_1(A)y\| = \|x\| \leq C\|y\|$. Then we can bound $\|x\|_{G(A)} := \|x\| + \|Ax\| \leq \|x\| + \|A_1x\| + \|x\| \leq (2C+1) \|A_1x\| = (2C+1)\|y\|$ so that $R_1(A)$ is bounded into $(\mathcal{D}(A), \|\cdot \|_{G(A)})$. (Hopefully this is clear enough, it was a bit difficult to give a proper explanation in the comment section, sorry!)

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure how we can conclude that these extensions coincide. I only know about the uniqueness of an extension for a fixed norm on the target space. (BTW, I've asked asked a separate question for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3098916/47771)

Comment: @0xbadf00d Since the graph norm dominates the original norm, the extension I produce (with respect to the graph norm) is also continuous with respect to the original norm with respect to which you extend. This means it is a candidate for the extension that you produce. Since you know your extension is unique, this means my extension and your extension coincide.

Comment: @RhysSteele Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89207/discussion-between-rhys-steele-and-0xbadf00d).

Comment: @RhysSteele (Don't know if you've seen it, but I've asked one other thing in the chat).